# php code entering my html

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert data from a php page into my mySQL databse. when I refresh the page parts of my php code is being displayed on the page rather than being processed below is my code(sensitive info blocked):

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "*******";
  $password = "*******";
  $dbname = "accounts";

  // Create connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
  VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

and this is a screenshot of the "view source", as you can see it sort of stops doing it's PHP and displaying into my page. thoughts?

[image: view source]

Comment: I don’t see there’s any issue with your code. You sure your server is on and the php lib is installed?

Comment: may be bad configuration in your vhosts, htaccess, bad rights file/folders, or you apache stop for some reason ... did you got some errors in your logs?

Comment: File is `.php`? Accessing with `http://`?

Comment: Which web server are you using? Does it support PHP at all ?

Answer (score 1):

Hello bro your code is alright i test it on my local server. i think you are not saving file with correct extension. or your mysql table fields are incorrect if data is not inserting. Correct extension for php file name.php

Answer (score 1):

I think there is issue with either your **web server** or your **file extension**, Make sure your web server is active and file extension is **.php**